Google Cloud Function Fails to Build After Working with Python 3.9
I have a Google Cloud Function that was working fine with Python 3.9, but it has suddenly stopped working and fails when I try to test it manually.
Here’s the error I get in the GCP terminal log:
[10:37:08 PM] - Preparing function sources ...
[10:37:08 PM] - Building function sources ...
[10:37:09 PM] - Error: Command failed: cd /gcf-working-dir/function-sources && pack build gcf-ui-function --builder gcr.io/gae-runtimes/buildpacks/google-gae-18/python/builder --pull-policy if-not-present --env GOOGLE_FUNCTION_TARGET=hello_http --env GOOGLE_FUNCTION_SIGNATURE_TYPE=cloudevent --env GOOGLE_DEVMODE=1 --env GOOGLE_RUNTIME_VERSION=3.9
ERROR: failed to build: failed to fetch builder image 'gcr.io/gae-runtimes/buildpacks/google-gae-18/python/builder:latest': image 'gcr.io/gae-runtimes/buildpacks/google-gae-18/python/builder:latest' does not exist on the daemon: not found

> at checkExecSyncError (node:child_process:826:11)
    at execSync (node:child_process:900:15)
    at buildFunction (/app/app.runfiles/google3/cloud/console/web/functions/external/testing_server/workers/build_function_worker.js:17:38)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/app.runfiles/google3/cloud/console/web/functions/external/testing_server/workers/build_function_worker.js:35:131)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1095:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1124:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:816:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:79:12)
    at MessagePort.<anonymous> (node:internal/main/worker_thread:183:24)
ERROR: failed to build: failed to fetch builder image 'gcr.io/gae-runtimes/buildpacks/google-gae-18/python/builder:latest': image 'gcr.io/gae-runtimes/buildpacks/google-gae-18/python/builder:latest' does not exist on the daemon: not found

[10:37:09 PM] - Error while building function sources. Please check logs.

What I’ve Tried:

I’ve double-checked the Cloud Function settings and runtime (Python 3.9).

I’ve ensured that the image gcr.io/gae-runtimes/buildpacks/google-gae-18/python/builder:latest should be available.

I’ve also tried redeploying the function but it continues to fail with the same error.


Additional Info:

The function was previously working fine with no issues.

There are no recent updates on the function or its dependencies.

I have verified that the Google Cloud SDK is up to date.


Has anyone else encountered this issue? How can I resolve the missing builder image error (gcr.io/gae-runtimes/buildpacks/google-gae-18/python/builder:latest not found)?
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! I would try to make it run as it was running earlier. Right now it just keeps throwing error.

I think this is a known issue on Google Cloud Run Function, especially when you are using the “Test Function” feature that blocks the user from testing or deploying.
Upon checking the Cloud Run Function public issue tracker, there is an ongoing discussion about the issue.  You can also upvote or comment to monitor any updates coming directly from Google Cloud Support and Engineering Team. You can also check the release notes page to keep you updated on the recent updates about Cloud Run Function.
For the meantime, you can try the suggested workaround which is to test the function locally via the functions framework or the functions emulator.
